# Two matrix multiplication in OpenCL

Tags: performance, opencl, gpu, matrix-multiplication

Sorry if I'm asking a really simple question, but I couldn't find any related answer on the net.

I'm trying to perform two matrix multiplication on GPU using OpenCL, line R = A*B*C. They way I do, is by performing matrix multiplication on A and B, and then store the intermediate result (I) on the GPUs DRAM, and then do another matrix multiplication between I and C. My current kernel can also handle batches of matrices.

Here is the code for my MatMul kernel (It is just a basic version, without optimizations):

```
__kernel void MatrixMultiplication2 (const __global float* A,
                                     const __global float* B,
                                     __global float* C,
                                     const int A_height, const int A_width,
                                     const int B_height, const int B_width,
                                     const int C_height, const int C_width) {

        const int row = get_global_id (0);
        const int col = get_global_id (1);
        const int imgID = get_global_id (2);

        const int offsetA = A_height * A_width * imgID;
        const int offsetB = B_height * B_width * imgID;
        const int offsetC = C_height * C_width * imgID;

        float acc = 0.0f;

        for (int k = 0; k < A_width; k++) {
                acc += A[row*A_width + k + offsetA] * B[k*B_width + col + offsetB];
        }

        C[row*C_width + col + offsetC] = acc;


}
```

Here is also the related part in my host code for deploying matrix multiplications:

```
const size_t GWS1[3] = {A_height, B_width, batch_size};
const size_t LWS1[3] = {32, 32, 1};


const size_t GWS2[3] = {A_height, C_width, batch_size};
const size_t LWS2[3] = {32, 32, 1};

Event evKernel1 ("Kernel1");
Event evKernel2 ("Kernel2");

clFinish (queue);

high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel (queue,
                              kernel1,
                              3,
                              NULL,
                              GWS1,
                              LWS1,
                              0,
                              NULL,
                              &evKernel1.CLEvent());

clFinish (queue);
CL_CHECK_ERROR (err);
err = clFinish (queue);
CL_CHECK_ERROR (err);
err = clWaitForEvents (1, &evKernel1.CLEvent());
CL_CHECK_ERROR (err);
evKernel1.FillTimingInfo ();

err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel (queue,
                              kernel2,
                              3,
                              NULL,
                              GWS2,
                              LWS2,
                              0,
                              NULL,
                              &evKernel2.CLEvent());

clFinish (queue);
CL_CHECK_ERROR (err);
err =clFinish (queue);
CL_CHECK_ERROR (err);
err = clWaitForEvents (1, &evKernel2.CLEvent());
CL_CHECK_ERROR (err);

high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();

evKernel2.FillTimingInfo ();

readbackMemObject (queue, &mem_R, (int) sizeof (T), RSize, hostMem_R);
```

Is it the right way to do multi stage matrix multiplication on the GPU? I am deploying the first stage, and then wait until it finishes and then deploy the second one. The performance is really low in this scenario, and when I increase the batch size, it will decrease more. I just want to know if this is the normal way of doing sequential matrix multiplication or not.

Thanks,

Comment: 2 clFinish in a row must be slow. Also you are waiting for event after them. Also you are repeating this for next kernel too. Then you are also reading results at the end. Why don't you use only a single clfinish at the end?

Comment: I just wanna make sure the first stage is completed before second stage is being fired.

Comment: My general question here is, is this the right way of performing multi stage operations? Like neural networks or any other things like that?